# A voltmeter is connected in parallel across the load. Why?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Voltmeter is connected in parallel across the load. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Objects in parallel experience same potential. Thus a voltmeter connected parallel to the load measures same voltage dropped across the load.